# Filter List of Orders by Product Tags

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using WooCommerce REST API to list all the orders. Now I have to filter the list by product tags. Is there any way to accomplish this with a single GET request like this:

```
curl https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/orders?filter["tag"]="custom_tag" \
    -u consumer_key:consumer_secret
```

Any thoughts will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking how to filter by tag or attribute, but nothing work, only the filter by category
products?filter[category]=my_category/
Do you have some updates ? :)
Thank you